# alterar texto da div com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tenho um 'input' e uma 'div':

```
<input  type='text' id='valor' name='valor'>

<div id='valor'><b>R$ 1,00</b></div>
```

Bom preciso trocar o valor de 1,00 pelo valor que eu digitar no input. Como posso fazer isso em perder o css da div valor?

Queria fazer isso usando Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, primeiro de tudo, você não pode ter dois elementos com o mesmo ID na página, não é uma boa prática. Troque o ID do seu input para algo diferente tipo `valorInput`, ou use uma classe.

Você pode usar o evento change do jQuery para isso dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#valorInput').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#valor b').text('R$ '+value);
  });
});
```

Se voce tiver uma estrutura mais ou menos assim:

```
<input  type='text' id='valorInput' name='valor'>

<div id='valor'><b>R$ 1,00</b></div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qzqkmjah/

Comment: Fazendo uma observação na resposta do @KhaosDoctor, o evento _change_ do jQuery, só é executado quando perde o foco do _input_, caso você queira executar a função enquanto o usuário digita, há os eventos _keyup_, _keydown_ e _keypress_, depende qual ação você precisa. Para saber mais sobre os eventos: [jQuery Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Comment: muito obriga aos 2 pela ajuda :) deu certinho aqui